# Rails Background jobs uses all CPU memory and blocks UI actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process, resque

I am using `resque` gem to process background jobs for import and exports task (Asynchronous). These jobs were using almost all CPU memory if import/export task increasing and it blocks UI(Web) actions also. I am not sure what is the best way to optimize this?

Comment: What do your jobs entail?  What are you running this on?  Could you use nice to reduce the priority of your processes?

Comment: There might be many reasons why, it all depends on your code and hardware.

Comment: I am running sync i.e Import and Export data for 1000+ objects and each object has more than 200+ sub-background jobs running in parallel and these data are changing very frequently so I have to run sync on daily basis and these syncs are running in different -2 time to avoid high CPU memory usage but still, I am getting 100% CPU utlization in peak hours.